# How could I seasonally adjust data series and constrain produced data only to 0 or positive values?

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I would like to seasonally adjust data series that cannot be negative. How I could do this? Currently I am using seas in R. Is it possible to constrain the output series to 0 or positive values?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you want exactly, but here are two options that may help you:

**Option 1, offsetting:** Subtract min(seriesX) from each element of output seriesX;

data.table style:

`seriesX[, value := value - min(value)]`

**Option 2, thresholding:** Transform each seriesX element smaller than 0 - to 0

data.table style:

`seriesX[value < 0, value := 0]`